# WCF UserNamePasswordValidator - Access credentials after validation

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using the `UserNamePasswordValidator` class as part of the `UserName` security with WCF.  This all works great and the `Validate` function of the class gets called and works properly.

How then can I find out what `UserName` was used in my service functions?

For example say if a client connects and requests a list of logs using something like

```
IList<Log> Logs() { ... }
```

How can that function know which UserName was used on that request?

What I want to do is log what UserName calls what function within the service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure, but you may be looking for

```
var userName = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is something in the operation context. Try this:

```
OperationContext oc = OperationContext.Current;
ServiceSecurityContext ssc = oc.ServiceSecurityContext;
string client = ssc.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
```