# How to get Custom UserName/Password in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I am using clientCredentailType as Username under security mode under Message. I have created a Custom username and password validator class to verify the username and password.

I want to use these credentials (username,password) for authorization to different operations within the service. I want to know whats the best way to store the username and password for reuse. Should I use my custom validator class to store these in static variables so that they are accessible everywhere ?

Why can't I use System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name, I tried to get the username but it does not show me anything and how can I get Password ?

Thanks
Adnan

Answer (score 1):

Only process and use the credentials in your custom validator. If the credentials are valid, use a custom authorization policy to prepare a custom principal with a set of roles for that user and decorate your service methods with PrincipalPermission attributes.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true, Role = "ClearedForUsingFoo")]
public void Foo(string bar)
{
...


class AuthorizationPolicy : IAuthorizationPolicy
{
    public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
    {
        // get the authenticated client identity
        IIdentity identity = GetClientIdentity(evaluationContext);

        // set the custom principal
        evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = new CustomPrincipal(identity);

        return true;
    }

    public ClaimSet Issuer
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return "FooBarApp.AuthorizationPolicy"; }
    }

    private static IIdentity GetClientIdentity(EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
    {
        object obj;
        if (!evaluationContext.Properties.TryGetValue("Identities", out obj))
            throw new Exception("No Identity found");

        IList<IIdentity> identities = obj as IList<IIdentity>;
        if (identities == null || identities.Count <= 0)
            throw new Exception("No Identity found");

        return identities[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I am new to identity framework and I just went through some of its documentation. I am a bit confused that how can Identity framework help me if I have my own custom database with users and roles. How can I map my custom users/roles with WIF so that I can use them as anyother builtin roles functionality i.e. (Windows Account, ASPNET Roles etc). If you have or know any article on this please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The CurrentPrincipal property of the thread is the Windows identity the **service** is running under. Your service is receiving the **client** identity in the form of a user name/password and it has no relationship to the service identity. WCF supports [impersonation and delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx) but not using a custom identity scheme like your service is using.

The accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510850/wcf-usernamepasswordvalidator-access-credentials-after-validation) may be what you are looking for. If that doesn't work, it gets pretty ugly pretty quickly to do this manually in code.

Comment: OperationContext oc = OperationContext.Current;
            ServiceSecurityContext ssc = oc.ServiceSecurityContext;
            string client = ssc.PrimaryIdentity.Name; 

Is there any way to get the password as well ?

Comment: Short answer is no. The security context will provide the authorized user "identity" which usually consist of the user/account name and possibly what roles/groups the user is a member of. Since the password is only useful for authentication, it is never exposed for an already authenticated user. Basically, the only time its available is during the authentication process. It would be extremely insecure to allow any process to have access to the password outside of the authentication process.